# Issue while adding inline user profile form with Django admin user form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I got stuck with small issue in django project, I hope I can get some good answers here.

I have added user profile inline form with django User form by doing code like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from djangocalendar.models import UserProfile

from tableapp.models import *
from djangocalendar.models import *
from django import forms

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = True
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def clean_first_name(self):
        if self.cleaned_data["first_name"].strip() == '':
            raise ValidationError("First name is required.")
        return self.cleaned_data["first_name"]

    def clean_last_name(self):
        if self.cleaned_data["last_name"].strip() == '':
            raise ValidationError("Last name is required.")
        return self.cleaned_data["last_name"]


# Define a new User admin
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    inlines = UserProfileInline,


# Register your models here
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Issue I am facing with this, This inline appears with User Add form and with Change user form too. I don't want it to display while adding user.

Like In this screenshot: Inline form appears with add User form! I don't want this to add inline form here. But I want to display inline form while editing user with other forms like personal form, information form.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution

## Define a new User admin

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    inlines = UserProfileInline,

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(MyUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
```